# Using none for three or more nos. in mathematics

Tags: conjunctions, negation, mathematics, logic

Which form is correct?

> None of A,B or C divides X

or

> None of A,B and C divides X

Comment: I'd say they're both "acceptable", but personally I'd prefer ***or*** rather than ***and***. Note that some people will be happy with ***Neither** A **nor** B **nor** C works*, but others will reject this on the grounds that ***neither/either*** only work with ***two*** alternatives.

Comment: Do we say: "A, B or C divides X", where A, B and C are numbers?

Comment: @Lambie: For smaller values of A,B,C *(2, 3 and 4 [all] divide [into] 12)* we wouldn't use ***or*** because it's "obvious". But it wouldn't be ridiculous to say something like *1234567, 7654321 **or** 292929 divides 87576465465467548765887* - with the implication that *only one* of the first three values divides exactly into the final one (perhaps it's a super-hard mental arithmetic test, where the addressee is being invited to guess / figure out when one that is).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That was not my question. **My question is**: Do we say in the English language that: 2,3, 4 divides 12?? Or do we usually say: 12 is divisible by 2, 3 and 4. (I was not addressing the the word or.) And **none of x** seems really wrong to me.

Comment: @Lambie: It kinda depends on the exact context. For most *likely* contexts we'd almost certainly tend to prefer *12 is divisible by 2, 3 and 4*, but it's easy to imagine contexts where attention is focused on the divisors rather than the dividend. *We're only really interested in single-digit numbers here. In which context it's important to remember that 2, 3, 4 and 6 divide [exactly] [into] 12.*

Comment: I don't know whether this is any particular qualification. But I teach math, and to me it sounds natural to say that 2, 3 and 4 divide 12. I think this is to Lambie's question about active and passive voice. It would sound stranger to say that 2, 3 or 4 divides 12; I see the logic of pairing "and" with "divide" and "or" with "divides," but I don't know why we should say "or" if the statement is true of all of them. I agree that if a quiz is intended, and one of the numbers is a factor but we want to avoid identifying it, then "or" is better.

Comment: I suppose that the original question is asking whether we should say "None of A, B and C" or "None of A, B or C," without any important connection to the normal syntax when discussing division.

Comment: @Chaim Thank you for reducing my anxiety. Right. I see. What do you say about: none of?

Comment: @Chaim: How about *None of A,B **and/or** C **are factors** of X?* Does that change your opinion re the ***and/or*** choice?

Comment: There's also the matter of "plurality" for such expressions. Should it be *None of 5, 7, and (or?) 9 **are** factors of 12,* or ***...is a** factor of 12?* I have no strong opinion on that one (both forms are "awkward", but I can't say I think either is any more or less grammatical than the other).

Comment: *"2 **divides** 12"* sounds weird to my American ears, and would be confusing.  Instead we say *"2 **divides into** 12 (evenly)"*.

Comment: I don't know. A few minutes spent thinking about this and looking around on the web have got me nowhere. I guess that to me the two alternatives in the original question both seem grammatical but a bit unnatural.

Comment: I too think either of them means the same, just used at times to confuse the student. One of the cases when language makes Maths difficult..

Comment: @Lambie As a point of style, it might be nice to use "and" where possible because it is more versatile, used with all of the quantifiers. We could say "Of Jones, Smith and Brown, two are present, one is willing but none is qualified." It would be a bit of a distraction to require a different phrasing for the "none" part.

Comment: I'd go with: X is not divisible by A, B or C as it makes it clearer. A,B or C doesn't sound natural to me and A,B and C => not all in my mind

Comment: @Andrew  in number theory, where questions of divisibility are common and important, it is usual to say "X divides Y" , and highly unusual to say "X divides into Y". It is also common to say "X is a factor of Y". 'Evenly" is always implied and never explicitly stated in such statements.

Comment: A, B, and C do not divide X.  What's all the hubbub here?

Comment: In standard mathematical English, the expression is: X is not divisible by A, B and C.

Comment: @Chaim I believe pondial issues are in play here. Saying "2,3, or 4 divide 12" has sense of American to me. I don't think a maths teacher in Britain would say it quite like that - perhaps more likely something like "2,3, or 4 are factors of 12", or "2,3,or 4 divide exactly into 12".

Comment: @WS2 Well I have no recollection of this conversation at all, but I see in the record that four and a half years ago I suggested And-Divide, not Or-Divide. And as I said then, I don't really see the logic of your second suggestion, using 'or' where all examples are factors, but perhaps that's a stylistic choice. But I doubt that math teachers anywhere would specify that A "divides exactly into" another number, because in the jargon of math we would never say that 12 is divisible by 5, in the broad sense you seem to contemplate in which every (non-zero) number divides every other number.

Comment: The only divisibility we ever comment on is dividing 'exactly'; that's what we call divisibility. And as to the pond, I think that British people generally improve on American English by inserting an extra "u" somewhere in the spelling, so perhaps it should be "2, 3 our 4." But if you don't get the President on that phone... you'll have to answer to the Coca-Cola Company.

Comment: @Chaim *Well I have no recollection of this conversation at all...*  What conversation? Are you confusing a comment of mine with that of someone else?

Comment: @WS2 No, I don't think I've confused comments. I was just observing that in December of 2022 you were joining a conversation about a question asked in April of 2018, and I played my small role then and had forgotten all about it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither form is desirable.  They are hard to understand.  Generally starting a sentence with *None of* and then iterating a list of items to which *None of* applies is cumbersome.  For example, *None of my kids, Carol's kids, or Lester's kids swim well.*  If **none** of them swim well you don't need to specifically call out the **none**.  I will understand that from context.

> *My kids, Carol's kids, and Lester's kids do not swim well.*

That means **none** swim well.

> *A, B, and C do not divide X.*

Once again that means **none**.  No reason to say it.

For sentences with a single subject *none of* works very well.

> *None of our kids swim well.*

> *None of those numbers divide X.*

It's when you add the itemized list to *none of* that things start getting cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get real. [joke]

There are many shortcuts or tricks that allow you to test whether a number, or dividend, is divisible by a given divisor. This page focuses on the most-frequently studied divisibility rules which involve divisibility by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, and by 11

[arithmetic](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/arithmetic/numbers/divisibility-rules-and-tests.php)

Finally, none of refers to a portion of something. Numbers here are not portions. They are whole numbers.

- 12 cannot be divided by 5, 10 or 3.

We would never say in English: None of 5, 10 or 3 etc.

Why? Because it would imply that 5 can be broken down into portions. It can't. It can only be rewritten with other whole numbers: 2+ 2+1 is 5.

AS IN: None of the pie or pies were left after the party. The guests had eaten the whole thing or all of them.

Comment: "None" here would simply refer to the portion *of the listed items*, not that any of the individual items can be broken into portions. I don't see any real difference between "None of these numbers are divisible by 2", "None of them are divisible by 2", and "None of 3, 5, or 7 are divisible by 2." You can pretty much always replace a pronoun ("None of them") with the noun(s) it represents ("None of 3, 5, or 7").

Comment: @NuclearHoagie No, it would not. For that to be the case, linguistically, it would have to say: **None of these numbers (3, 5 or 7)** are divisors of 12.  None of 3, 5 or 7 [big fat buzzer]. None of the numbers in the set [OK]

Comment: **None of the numbers in the list; None of the numbers given to you etc.**  Just like you can't do this: None of Jerry, Louise or Martin were on the bus.

Comment: I cannot imagine any situation where a sentence could be ungrammatical with a noun  ("None of [3, 5, or 7] are divisible by 2") , but grammatical when directly substituting a pronoun instead ("None of [them] are divisible by 2"). Pronoun substitution changes absolutely nothing about a sentence's grammatical structure.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie It's not the pronoun.  It's the compound subject.  See my post.  *None of* does not work with a compound subject sentence. *None of sheep, hamsters, or rabbits are carnivores.*  That is ungrammatical but *None of them are carnivores* is grammatical.  *None of* only works to differentiate between members of a group, not between groups themselves.  We use a different structure to differentiate multiple subjects.  *Sheep, hamsters, and rabbits are not carnivores.*  No need for none.

Comment: none of a non-count noun, or none of [a list, or members of a group]. None of the horses, sheep or goats were in the field.

Comment: @Lambie - Good point.  Now I'm wondering if this is a contextual construct similar to the difference in *I did not meet Louis in Rome* and *I never met Louis in Rome.*

Comment: @EllieK Sorry, don't follow you.